# Is it possible to perform multiple DB operations on two sets of documents in single transaction in MongoDB using morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Can the following two update operations take place in one single transaction?

```
Query<Group> query1 = createQuery().disableValidation().field("users").equal(user.getUserId()).retrievedFields(true, "_id","users"); 
UpdateOperations<Group> ops1 = createUpdateOperations().removeAll("users", user);       
update(query1, ops1);

Query<Group> query = createQuery().field("_id").in(groupList);
UpdateOperations<Group> ops = createUpdateOperations().add("users", user);
update(query, ops);
```

Comment: There are no transactions in mongodb, so what do you think the answer would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no *multidocument* transactions in mongodb.  Writes to a single document are atomic, however.  So no, there is no way to do that via morphia either.